# How to stream/read middle portion of binary file and write to another file in standard c++?

Tags: c++, stream, fstream, binaryfiles

If I have file with 1000 bytes (just simple example), how to read bytes from 300 bytes to 700 bytes and write that portion to new binary file, especially with fstream? 
The process should be platform-independent (with c++11) and works even for large file.

Note that,
I don't care how long (performance) it will take provided it doesn't fail. So I like the method that writes bytes by bytes to file similar to when you download large file.

There might be many questions like this on web but all of them either deal with copying entire file, reading portion of text file or just for only small file that is possible to hold as variable of byte array and manipulate it.

Please, help me.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell:

Open the file for reading. Seek to offset 300. Read 400 bytes into a buffer. Close the file.
Open the second file for writing. Write the buffer to the second file. Close the second file. Free the buffer.

Comment: Ok, but can you help me with sample codes? I can do with Java but I can't in CPP. @jesper Juhl

Comment: @WailenB I could, but I'm not going to. This is not a code writing service. But I *will* point you at some things to look into on your own: to seek you can use [fstream::seekg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) or [std::fseek](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fseek) if you are not using `fstream`. For a buffer you can use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that policy! I will try but if you find blog about that please mention here because these solutions (answers) are not just for me but for everyone, even those with advanced knowledge.

Comment: Reminder:  open the file in *binary* mode so that the OS doesn't perform any translations on your data.  For example, some operating systems recognize 0x1A as an end of file marker.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use fopen to open the binary file, 2nd parameter may need 'rb'
2. Use fseek to reposition stream position indicator
3. Use fread to read how long part you want to
4. Use fwrite to complete the target file.
   All of them are C++ Std.

Comment: Thank you! @Yang These steps are very helpful and easy for those who have sufficient knowledge of it. But for me still I have to take more time to master.